# How does a Rust `Stream` understand when to call `poll_next`?

Tags: rust, stream, future

`Stream`'s [documentation](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.12/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html#return-value) says:

> Implementations will ensure that the current task will be notified when the next value may be ready.

How does the stream understand when to call `poll_next` again?

Answer (score 3):

When you are implementing a `Stream`, you know what the `Stream` does since, well, you are the one implementing it. Since you know what it does, you also know when a new item might be ready, thus you can write code that triggers a notification at the right time.

To give an example, if you are implementing a message passing channel, the sender and receiver will have a shared piece of memory, and when you call `poll_next` on the receiver, the receiver will take the `Waker` from inside the `Context` argument, and store it in this shared memory. When a message is sent, the sender will use the `Waker` to send the notification, since this is the event that indicates that a value is available on the receiver.

To give another example, if you are implementing a timer (e.g. [`Interval`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1/tokio/time/struct.Interval.html)), the `poll_next` method on the `Stream` will give the provided `Waker` to another piece of code, which is then responsible for sleeping until the timer should trigger, at which point this other piece of code will send a notification using the `Waker` it got from the `Stream`. In Tokio, this other piece of code is an internal component of the Tokio runtime. (This is why Tokio timers cannot be used outside a Tokio runtime.)